# Is it possible to change the UI color of a single program in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, colors, user-interface

I know it's possible to set the global UI colors in Windows 7 via the system preferences. But is it possible to set a different UI color scheme just for one program?

I am asking, because I'm using Aptana Studio with a black text field and the grey UI elements look rather ugly (Aptana resp. Eclipse is using the system UI colors for its windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to customize UI colors for each application, but you can try to create manifest file for older application, so it will make use of common controls v6 DLL - modern buttons, color scheme, gradient background on tabs etc.

A brief guide:
http://delphi.about.com/library/bluc/text/uc111601a.htm